# OpenIddict Authorization Code Flow & Refresh Tokens

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, refresh-token, openiddict

I've been experimenting with the OpenIddict sample projects, more specifically [Zirku](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/Zirku) to better understand Authorization Code Flow and Introspection.

Based on a fair bit of research I've been able to develop a Client MVC Web App, an Auth Server, and a separate Resource Server (API), all of which were influenced by the samples linked above. In testing I've been able to login and access an endpoint from my API that is prefixed with the `[Authorize]` attribute successfully, by passing the access token in the request header. After waiting for a minute any attempt to access the API again, will result  in a `401 Unauthorized` as expected since the access token has now expired based on the Auth Server configuration. The only way to call the endpoint successfully after this, is to complete a logout and login thus generating a new access token and a grace period of a minute before it expires.

I've therefore implemented Refresh Tokens, through adding the RefreshTokenFlow and required offline_access scope to the relevant projects as seen below. Whilst I have the ability to obtain the access and refresh tokens in my Client application I am unsure on how to handle the process of using the refresh token to obtain a new access token.

In essence, how do I use the refresh token to obtain a new access token, once the original is nearing its expiry, and how can use the new token throughout my client application until it needs refreshing, or until the user has singed out? Presumably I need to call the connect/token endpoint with a grant_type of `refresh_token`, but will this update the HttpContext in my client app with the new tokens?

Client MVC:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/login";
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "ExampleClientId";
    options.ClientSecret = "ExampleClientSecret";

    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;

    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001/";

    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Scope.Add("roles");
    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
    options.Scope.Add("example_api");

    options.MapInboundClaims = false;

    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
});

...

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();
```

Auth Server:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    options.UseOpenIddict();
});

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddDefaultUI();

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = Claims.Name;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = Claims.Subject;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = Claims.Role;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.EmailClaimType = Claims.Email;

    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
});

builder.Services.AddQuartz(options =>
{
    options.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
    options.UseSimpleTypeLoader();
    options.UseInMemoryStore();
});

builder.Services.AddQuartzHostedService(options => options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);

builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddCore(options =>
    {   
        options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
               .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();

        options.UseQuartz();
    })
    .AddServer(options =>
    {
        options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
               .SetLogoutEndpointUris("/connect/logout")
               .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token")
               .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/connect/userinfo")
               .SetIntrospectionEndpointUris("/connect/introspect");

    
        options.RegisterScopes(Scopes.Email, Scopes.Profile, Scopes.Roles, Scopes.OfflineAccess);

        options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
               .AllowRefreshTokenFlow()
               .SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
               .SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));

   
        options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
               .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

        options.UseAspNetCore()
               .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
               .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
               .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
               .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough()
               .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration();
    })
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        options.UseLocalServer();

        options.UseAspNetCore();
    });

// Register the worker responsible for seeding the database.
// Note: in a real world application, this step should be part of a setup script.
builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

...

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();
```

Woker.cs:

```
public class Worker : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public Worker(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        => _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateAsyncScope();

        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

        var manager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOpenIddictApplicationManager>();

        if (await manager.FindByClientIdAsync("SampleClientMVC") == null)
        {
            await manager.CreateAsync(new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
            {
                ClientId = "ExampleClientId",
                ClientSecret = "ExampleClientSecret",
                ConsentType = ConsentTypes.Explicit,
                DisplayName = "MVC Client Application",
                PostLogoutRedirectUris =
            {
                new Uri("https://localhost:7001/signout-callback-oidc")
            },
                RedirectUris =
            {
                new Uri("https://localhost:7001/signin-oidc")
            },
                Permissions =
            {
                Permissions.Endpoints.Authorization,
                Permissions.Endpoints.Logout,
                Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
                Permissions.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode,
                Permissions.GrantTypes.RefreshToken,
                Permissions.ResponseTypes.Code,
                Permissions.Scopes.Email,
                Permissions.Scopes.Profile,
                Permissions.Scopes.Roles,
                Permissions.Prefixes.Scope + "example_api"
            },
                Requirements =
            {
                Requirements.Features.ProofKeyForCodeExchange
            }
            });
        }

        if (await manager.FindByClientIdAsync("sample_resource_server") is null)
        {
            await manager.CreateAsync(new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
            {
                ClientId = "example_resource_server",
                ClientSecret = "ExampleResourceServerSecret",
                Permissions =
                {
                    Permissions.Endpoints.Introspection
                }
            });
        }

        var scopeManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOpenIddictScopeManager>();

        if (await scopeManager.FindByNameAsync("example_api") is null)
        {
            await scopeManager.CreateAsync(new OpenIddictScopeDescriptor
            {
                Name = "example_api",
                Resources =
                {
                    "example_resource_server"
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Token Endpoint:

```
[HttpPost("~/connect/token"), Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Exchange()
{
    var request = HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest() ??
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The OpenID Connect request cannot be retrieved.");

    if (request.IsAuthorizationCodeGrantType())
    {
        var principal = (await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)).Principal;

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return Forbid(
                authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                properties: new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error] = Errors.InvalidGrant,
                    [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription] = "The token is no longer valid."
                }));
        }

        if (!await _signInManager.CanSignInAsync(user))
        {
            return Forbid(
                authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                properties: new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error] = Errors.InvalidGrant,
                    [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription] = "The user is no longer allowed to sign in."
                }));
        }

        foreach (var claim in principal.Claims)
        {
            claim.SetDestinations(GetDestinations(claim, principal));
        }

        return SignIn(principal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    else if (request.IsRefreshTokenGrantType())
    {
        var info = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(info.Principal);
        if (user == null)
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error] = Errors.InvalidGrant,
                [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription] = "The refresh token is no longer valid."
            });

            return Forbid(properties, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        if (!await _signInManager.CanSignInAsync(user))
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error] = Errors.InvalidGrant,
                [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription] = "The user is no longer allowed to sign in."
            });

                return Forbid(properties, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        var principal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);

        foreach (var claim in principal.Claims)
        {
            claim.SetDestinations(GetDestinations(claim, principal));
        }

        return SignIn(principal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("The specified grant type is not supported.");
}
```

Resource Server - API:

```
builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        options.SetIssuer("https://localhost:7235/");
        options.AddAudiences("example_resource_server");

          options.UseIntrospection()
           .SetClientId("example_resource_server")
           .SetClientSecret("ExampleResourceServerSecret");

    options.UseSystemNetHttp();

    options.UseAspNetCore();
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

...

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Hey, would you share your code so I could look at your implementation for guidance?

Answer (score 0):

if you have saved the token in cookie,I think you could try as below to check the remaining time of the token ,and you could try to get a new token with httpclient

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/login";
        options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
        {
            
             OnValidatePrincipal = async CookieValiCoText =>
            {
                var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
                var expiresAt = CookieValiCoText.Properties.GetTokenValue("expires_in");
                .......some logical codes
//to get the accesstoken with refresh token if the token expires soon
    if ( about toexpires )
                {
                    var refreshToken = CookieValiCoText.Properties.GetTokenValue("refresh_token");
                    
                    var response = await new HttpClient().RequestRefreshTokenAsync(new RefreshTokenRequest
                    {
                        Address = "your exchange end point",
                        ClientId = "ExampleClientId",
                        ClientSecret = "ExampleClientSecret",
                        RefreshToken = refreshToken
                    });
    .......
```